# Как при использовании Slick Slider'а сделать крайние элементы с другим класом?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js, slider-slick.js

[image: На картинке видно слайдер у которого боковой элемент справа не по центру, видно серый слой поверх него]

Есть идея добавить класс к боковому элементу:

// который будет добавлять сверху прозрачный сероватый слой.

```
.grd:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: #9b9b9ba3;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Известно что у центрального элемента слайдера есть класс **slick-current**, а также у соседних есть **slick-active** и у него самого.

Пробовал добавлять этот класс с помощью **next()**, но получилось так только с одним элементом, и при этом когда я клацал слайдер ( меняются классы видимых слайдов ), а класс не изменялся. *Всё дело в динамических элементах DOM?*

// настройки слайдера

```
$('.slider').slick({
         infinite: true,
         slidesToShow: 3,
         centerMode: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.slick-arrow').on('click', function(){
        var nExt = $('.slick-current').next().next();
        var pRev = $('.slick-current').prev().prev();
        $('.slick-active').removeClass('grd');
        nExt.addClass('grd');
        pRev.addClass('grd');

})
```

Сделал таким не хитрым способом сработало